# How to escape closed bracket "]" in regex in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I'm trying to use `gsub` in R to replace a bunch of weird characters in some strings I'm processing.  Everything works, except whenever I throw in "]" it makes the whole thing do nothing.  I'm using `\\` like `gsub("[\\?\\*\\]]", "", name)` but it's still not working.  Here's my actual example:

```
name <- "R U Still Down? [Remember Me]"
```

what I want is: `names` to be `"R U Still Down Remember Me"`

when I do:
    `names <- gsub("[\\(\\)\\*\\$\\+\\?'\\[]", "", name)`
it semi-works and I get `"R U Still Down Remember Me]"`

but when I do:
    `names <- gsub("[\\(\\)\\*\\$\\+\\?'\\[\\]]", "", name)`
nothing happens.  (i.e. I get `"R U Still Down? [Remember Me]"`)

Any ideas?  I've tried switching around the order of things, etc.  But I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 12):

Just enable `perl=TRUE` parameter.

```
> gsub("[?\\]\\[*]", "", name, perl=T)
[1] "R U Still Down Remember Me"
```

And escape only the needed characters.

```
> gsub("[()*$+?'\\[\\]]", "", name, perl=T)
[1] "R U Still Down Remember Me"
```

Answer (score 8):

You can switch the order of the character class without escaping.

```
name <- 'R U Still Down? [Remember Me][*[[]*'
gsub('[][?*]', '', name)
# [1] "R U Still Down Remember Me"
```

If you want to remove all punctuation characters, use the POSIX class `[:punct:]`

```
gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', name)
```

This class in the ASCII range matches all *non-controls*, *non-alphanumeric*, *non-space* characters.

```
ascii <- rawToChar(as.raw(0:127), multiple=T)
paste(ascii[grepl('[[:punct:]]', ascii)], collapse="")
# [1] "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~"
```

Comment: @MichaelChirico - when hwnd answers a regex question, I don't even bother.  He's boss.

Comment: Thanks hwnd.  I'd say that qualifies as boss.  Just another question: I don't totally understand what's happening with `gsub('[][?*]', '', name)`

Comment: Would you mind just explaining why I don't have to escape the other characters?  I'm gonna run this in a for loop over a bunch of different names, so I just wanna make sure I understand what's going on under the hood.

Comment: Inside a character class, different metacharacters apply. Namely, the caret `^`, the hyphen `-`, and the closing bracket `]`. You can avoid escaping these by positioning them so that their special meaning cannot apply. You can place `]` right after the opening bracket or right before the closing bracket and `^` anywhere except right after the opening bracket.

Comment: That makes perfect sense as far as the R parsing rules go, I just never thought of it that way. There needs to be some certain order to the bracketry.  Nice.  Thanks @hwnd.