# "Unknown collating element" from grepl

Tags: r, regex

I ran the following:

```
grepl('[^][.*+?(){}^|$]', c('a', 'ab', '(', '.', '['))
```

It failed with:

> invalid regular expression '[^][.*+?(){}^|$]', reason 'Unknown collating element'

It's supposed to be a negated (`^`) character class containing `.`, `*`, `+`, `?`, `^`, `|`, `$` and the paired delimiters `{}`, `()`, and `[]`.

What's wrong with my input and how can I fix it to run as intended? The first two elements should be `TRUE`, the rest `FALSE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `.` adter `[` is parsed by the default TRE library as a start of a collation element.

You simply need to change the order of the chars inside the bracket expression, put `.` not immediately after a `[` char:

```r
> grepl('[^][*.+?(){}^|$]', c('a', 'ab', '(', '.', '['))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

See the [TRE docs](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laurikari/tre/master/doc/tre-syntax.html):

> A collating element enclosed in `[.` and `.]`, matching the collating element. This can be used to include a literal `-` or a multi-character collating element in the list.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the docs, that's a great resource! I still have no idea what a "collating element" is but that's more than enough for this question :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with `[]` which are always tricky to insert correctly to a character class in R (see [How to escape closed bracket "]" in regex in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32041265/3576984)).

I couldn't find a way to get this to work with the default regex engine, but it's easy enough with escaping and setting `perl=TRUE`:

```
grepl('[^\\]\\[.*+?(){}^|$]', c('a', 'ab', '(', '.', '['), perl=TRUE)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I still don't know what to make of the cryptic error message about "collation".

Comment: There is no need for escaping. Try: `grepl('[^][.*+?(){}^|$]', c('a', 'ab', '(', '.', '['), perl=TRUE)` or `!grepl('[][.*+?(){}^|$]', c('a', 'ab', '(', '.', '['), perl=TRUE)`

Comment: or `grepl('[^][\\.*+?(){}^|$]', c('a', 'ab', '(', '.', '['))`